# jquery to clone form single field and increment id

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a single filed which i need to clone with a clone button and remove button to remove the cloned filed only
i made this simple script but i believe it contain something wrong since its not working :)

**HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="fileds">
    <select name="lang" id='lang'>
    <option>select language</option>
    </select>
     </div>
    </form>
    <div class="actions">
        <button class="clone">Clone</button> 
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var regex = /^(.*)(\d)+$/i;
    var cloneIndex = $("#lang").length;

    $("button.clone").live("click", function(){
        $(this).parents("#lang").clone()
            .appendTo(".fileds")
            .attr("id", "lang" +  cloneIndex)
            .find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 3) {
                    this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
                }
        });
        cloneIndex++;
    });


});
```

also i didn't find how to write the remove code for the remove button

Thank you

Comment: `#lang` is not parent of `.clone` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The `#lang` is not a parent of `.clone`

2) `.fields` should be `#field` as this is and ID

This code should work. Live [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhu52/3/)

```
$(function() {
    var counter = 1;

    $(".clone").live("click", function() {
        $("#lang:first").clone().appendTo("#fileds").addClass("lang" + counter);
        counter++
    });

    $(".remove").live('click', function() {
        if (counter > 1) { //Only apply if the lang field is more than 1
            counter = counter - 1;
            $("#lang:last").remove();
        }
    });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

the `lang` is not parent of the buttons, i have added a class and a handler for remove button, try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(".clone").on("click", function() { // you can use `on` instead of live which is deprecated 
        var cloneIndex = $(".lang").length; // you can find the the current length of `.lang` within the handler  
        $(".lang:last").clone() // clones the last element with class of `lang`
            .attr("id", "lang" +  cloneIndex)
            .appendTo("#fileds") // change this to id selector
        });
     $("button.remove").on("click", function(){ // '.remove' click handler
         $(".lang:last").remove()
     })  
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pkNe3/1/)

Comment: its working in example but when i used to use it into my page it doesn't work at it all

Comment: ok its working but it remove the source too i don't want to remove the original filed